# Google Maps E/GoogleCertificates: Failed to load googlecertificates. qw:No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and

Tags: android, google-maps, module

I am trying to connect google maps service.

I get this error message.

```
10-06 10:08:29.028 20796-20857/tuomastuokkola.google_maps_activity E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
10-06 10:08:29.028 20796-20857/tuomastuokkola.google_maps_activity E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
10-06 10:08:29.028 20796-20857/tuomastuokkola.google_maps_activity E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
10-06 10:08:30.916 20796-20854/tuomastuokkola.google_maps_activity E/GoogleCertificates: Failed to load com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates
                                                                                         qw: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:11)
                                                                                             at it.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:12)
                                                                                             at it.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:31)
                                                                                             at it.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:30)
                                                                                             at je.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:33)
                                                                                             at je.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:18)
                                                                                             at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fd.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:172)
                                                                                             at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ew.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:28)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I've tried using hashed restricted key and not restricted, not hashed key. Both give the same error. I've double checked that the keys are given properly using google documentation.

I don't find info about this specific error from anywhere.

I have tested with vide variety of google services and maps services versions. They all give the same error.

Maps app is working fine, but the app error in beginning does not let mqtt client do its thing, so I can't get data using the client.

I can provide more info, but I think I've done everything by the book (multiple times) and the dynamite module just keeps crashing with this same error message.

I can provide more on the bug, but I don't really know what info could help in exploring this error message.

Comment: share your error as text not as image

Comment: Edited error to be as a text instead of an image.